# Spark - Cassandra connection

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I am doing some processing using spark and want to push the data into Cassandra DB. this is done on 4 machines so its not locally. What is the best way Spark can push the data to Cassandra.

Any help will be helpful here.

THanks

Comment: why -1, I am genuinely asking this.

Comment: I didn't down-vote this question "yet". But anyway welcome to SO! Let me explain why it's been down-voted. Your question lacks of research and consistency. You seem to be asking for a tutorial or an opinion based answer which are both considered off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [Cassandra example distributed with Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/CassandraTest.scala).